# setState not updating or changing the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react project, using useState hook's setState is not changing my state value, after calling setState.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("Old");

useEffect(()=>{
    setName("New");

    console.log(name);  //Always prints "Old"
})
```

I tried adding a callback to `setName`, but it wouldn't accept that too.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. The example you shared makes sense to print the old value as the `set*` from React is not a sync operation, so you can't access the new value right away. You can read more [in React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally used the `useEffect` hook

Since `setState` is asynchronous, it was not updating the state immediately on call, it rather initiates the process of changing the state and javascript proceeds to execute to the lines below.

So I ended up using `useEffect` hook to execute anything that I wanted to run after the state `name` is changed, adding the state `name` as a dependency as shown below.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("Old");

useEffect(()=>{
    setName("New");
})


useEffect(()=>{

    console.log(name);  // This Always gets the new value
}, [name])
```